# How does .NET determine the Unicode category of a character?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, character

I was looking in mscorelib.dll with .NET Reflector, and stumbled upon the Char class. I always wondered how methods like Char.isLetter was done. I expected a huge list of test, but, buy digging a little bit, I found a really short code that determine the Unicode category. However, this code uses some kind of tables and some bitshifting voodoo. Can anyone explain to me how this is done, or point me to some resources?

**EDIT :** 
Here's the code. It's in System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.

```
internal static unsafe byte InternalGetCategoryValue(int ch, int offset)
{
    ushort num = s_pCategoryLevel1Index[ch >> 8];
    num = s_pCategoryLevel1Index[num + ((ch >> 4) & 15)];
    byte* numPtr = (byte*) (s_pCategoryLevel1Index + num);
    byte num2 = numPtr[ch & 15];
    return s_pCategoriesValue[(num2 * 2) + offset];
}
```

`s_pCategoryLevel1Index` is a `short*` and `s_pCategoryValues` is a `byte*`

Both are created in the CharUnicodeInfo static constructor :

```
 static unsafe CharUnicodeInfo()
{
    s_pDataTable = GlobalizationAssembly.GetGlobalizationResourceBytePtr(typeof(CharUnicodeInfo).Assembly, "charinfo.nlp");
    UnicodeDataHeader* headerPtr = (UnicodeDataHeader*) s_pDataTable;
    s_pCategoryLevel1Index = (ushort*) (s_pDataTable + headerPtr->OffsetToCategoriesIndex);
    s_pCategoriesValue = s_pDataTable + ((byte*) headerPtr->OffsetToCategoriesValue);
    s_pNumericLevel1Index = (ushort*) (s_pDataTable + headerPtr->OffsetToNumbericIndex);
    s_pNumericValues = s_pDataTable + ((byte*) headerPtr->OffsetToNumbericValue);
    s_pDigitValues = (DigitValues*) (s_pDataTable + headerPtr->OffsetToDigitValue);
    nativeInitTable(s_pDataTable);
}
```

Here is the UnicodeDataHeader.

```
internal struct UnicodeDataHeader
{
    // Fields
    [FieldOffset(40)]
    internal uint OffsetToCategoriesIndex;
    [FieldOffset(0x2c)]
    internal uint OffsetToCategoriesValue;
    [FieldOffset(0x34)]
    internal uint OffsetToDigitValue;
    [FieldOffset(0x30)]
    internal uint OffsetToNumbericIndex;
    [FieldOffset(0x38)]
    internal uint OffsetToNumbericValue;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    internal char TableName;
    [FieldOffset(0x20)]
    internal ushort version;
}
```

**Note :** I Hope this doesn't break any licence. If so, I'll remove the code.

Comment: can you post the decompiled code? not everyone has Reflector

Comment: .net developer without reflector? :P

Comment: no worries, I use it all the time :) I just figured some people might not have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic information is stored in `charinfo.nlp` which is embedded in `mscorlib.dll` as a resource and loaded at runtime. The specifics of the file are probably only known to Microsoft but suffice it to say that it probably is a lookup table in a fashion.

**EDIT**

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.unicodecategory.aspx):

> This enumeration is based on The Unicode Standard, version 5.0. For more information, see the "[UCD File Format](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#UCD_Files)" and "[General Category Values](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values)" subtopics at the Unicode Character Database.

Comment: It's not embedded, it's a linked resource.  /linkresource compiler option.  A random and boring detail, I know.

Comment: @Hans Passant, by "embedded" I of course meant that a "link was embedded". You believe me, right?

Comment: Yes. I've found that too. Sadly I cannot find a way to open this charinfo.nlp in a readable format. My knowledge of .NET at this point is limited, and Google only knows about Natural Language Processing...

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a b-tree of sorts.

The advantage is that a bunch of regions can all point to the same "character unknown" block, instead of needing a unique element in the array for each possible Char value.